# Identify this tea set (service) used in No Time To Die (2021)

Tags: props, set-design

In the final act, inside the secret base, Madeleine sits alone at a table in a room, only guarded by Primo and is expected to drink a cup of possibly poisonous tea. The cup is in front of her, with the matching tea pot next to it. Can anyone identify the maker or model of this tea service? Here are two screenshots from this scene:

[image: Madeleine sitting at a table holding the cup with Primo standing next to her. The tea pot is on the table.]

[image: Closeup of the tea cup on the table with tea pot standing right next to it.]

Comment: Without seeing marks on the bottom, it's hard to tell. But some guesses off the top of my head (because I collect fine art vintage/antiques) is perhaps Spode or Royal Crown Derby, but it could also be a knock off...Usually either company that uses "Imari" esque color pallet (Orange, Blue, Gold, on white) covers the pieces more fully...

Comment: Also is the teacup different? Is the rim color actually mint or is that shadows in the scene?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer, the teapot pattern is quite popular:

[image]

The teapot is a different set, a very commonly copied pattern, often collectively under the term imari, produced by many manufacturers such as H Colclough, Sutherland and Royal Albert & Royal Vale around 19th century, today considered antique victorian and edwardian china.